# Path-like search for a file

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Basically I am trying to get something similar to command search with `$PATH`, but with a different list of directories and the file I'm searching for is not executable.

The list of directories is fixed (I can pack it in a variable in the same format as PATH, or whatever), and I don't want to descend in subdirectories. I vaguely recall that bash `complete` has an option for this, but I read through the section and I can't spot it. Am I close?

Maybe something like this (assuming the file is in `~/lib`):

```
> filepath -p ".:/etc:$HOME/lib:$HOME/bin" foo
/home/alexis/lib/foo
```

To put it differently, I'm looking for something like `which` or `which -a`, whatever is easier, but it should not be limited to executables (and it should not search only `$PATH`, but I can work around that ;-)).

Comment: Is this something you want that helps you on an interactive command line, or something you want to be able to drop into a script (as a function, for example) so that it can look in a series of locations for a named file?

Comment: Use something like https://github.com/mgunyho/tere might be a lot easier

Comment: @roaima, it's for commandline use. It can be a script I call. I could write it from scratch in Python, but I figured that must be overkill, there must be tools that support it more directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reference @dhm but I like the bash commandline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` already supports multiple search paths

```
find . /etc ~/lib ~/bin -maxdepth 1 -name '*foo*'
```

Alternatively use [`fd`](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) which is significantly faster and far more featureful and more beautiful than find

```
fd --max-depth=1 foo . /etc ~/lib ~/bin
```

---

Another simple method but might not work for files with spaces or new lines:

```
SearchPaths=(/etc ~/lib ~/bin)
shopt -s nullglob
eval printf "%s " "${SearchPaths[@]/%/*foo*}"
```

I believe I've seen a simpler method using bash arrays that do direct file expansion but I can't recall it right now

Comment: max-depth=1 is a good idea, I had not thought of this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a bash function as wrapper for GNU `find`:

```
filepath () {
    local fp_path=${FP_PATH:-".:/etc:$HOME/lib:$HOME/bin"} fpath fquit=-quit
    local usage="usage: filepath [-a] [-p path[:path...]] expr"

    OPTIND=1
    while getopts :ap: opt; do
        case $opt in
            a)  fquit=
                ;;
            p)  fp_path=$OPTARG
                ;;
            *)  echo "$usage" >&2
                return 1
        esac
    done
    shift $((OPTIND-1))

    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "$usage" >&2
        return 1
    fi

    IFS=: read -r -a fpath <<<"$fp_path"
    find "${fpath[@]}" -maxdepth 1 \( -type f -o -type l \) -name "$1" -print $fquit 2>/dev/null
}
```

The default search path is defined in the first line of the function, use `:` as separator. It can be overridden by environment variable `FP_PATH` or option `-p`.
`find` exits after printing the first result unless option `-a` is used. The search is limited to regular files and symbolic links, adjust the options as needed.

Examples:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/bin /tmp/etc
$ touch ~/bin/foo /tmp/foo /tmp/etc/foo
$ filepath
usage: filepath [-a] [-p path[:path...]] expr

$ filepath -a -p /tmp:/tmp/etc 'fo*'
/tmp/foo
/tmp/etc/foo

$ filepath -p /tmp:/tmp/etc 'fo*'
/tmp/foo

$ FP_PATH=/tmp filepath foo
/tmp/foo

$ filepath foo
/home/freddy/bin/foo
```

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted but I didn't accept your answer because the task doesn't need all that chrome, `-maxdepth=1` is what I was missing to consider doing it with find. I really liked the PATH unpacking with IFS, though! :-)

Comment: Well, it's exactly what you wanted, a handy tool for the commandline using a PATH-like variable. Even the switches are as described.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed and I appreciate the effort... I did not sufficiently emphasize in the question that I was looking for a unix tool that already does this, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to store the list of directories in an array (`bash`) you can use code like this:

```
# Maybe in ~/.bashrc
filefindlist=(. /etc "$HOME/lib" "$HOME/bin" src/*)

filefind() {
    local ff
    for ff in "${filefindlist[@]}"
    do
        if [ -d "$ff" ] && [ -f "$ff/$1" ]
        then
            printf '%s\n' "$ff/$1"
            return 0
        fi
    done
    return 1
}
```

Usage

```
filefind program.c
```

Note that any variables and shell globs - wildcards - will be evaluated at the time the array `filefindlist` is defined. So if you have `src/one` and later create `src/two` then `src/*` will have only expanded to `src/one`. Next time you define the array, though, it will include `src/one` and `src/two`.

If you want an exact implementation of your suggestion in the question, something like this could work:

```
filefind() {
    local fl="$FILEFINDLIST" fp ff

    [ "$1" = '-p' ] && fl="$2" && shift 2    # Override default search list
    readarray -d: -t fp <<<"$fl"             # Convert to array

    for ff in "${fp[@]}"
    do
        if [ -d "$ff" ] && [ -f "$ff/$1" ]
        then
            printf '%s\n' "$ff/$1"
            return 0                         # Only print first match
        fi
    done
    return 1
}
```

Usage

```
FILEFINDLIST='.:$HOME/lib:$HOME/bin'

filefind -p ".:/etc:$HOME/lib:$HOME/bin" program.c
filefind program.c
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote in the comment I was looking for a unix utility or built-in command that can be used to do this more cleanly. The accepted answer does it in just four tokens, plus the list of folders and the filename.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you've got something that sufficiently approximates what you described in your question, @alexis. One of the really good things about UNIX-derived systems is that one can write one's own utilities, add them to a directory in the `$PATH`, and they become as easy to access as standard ones.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
filepath() print -rC1 -- ${(s[:])^1}/$^@[2,-1](N)
```

Then:

```
$ filepath .:/etc:$HOME/lib:$HOME/bin ls issue python
/etc/issue
/home/chazelas/lib/python
/home/chazelas/bin/ls
```